# Logic behind recursively building a binary expression tree from a stack

Tags: c, binary-tree, expression-trees

I am building binary expression tree that uses operators, variables, and integers.

The user enters the expression and we tokenize it based on spaces and place each token into the stack.

For example,

User enters : a b +

Our stack becomes Stack = ["+", "b", "a"]

I have a function that creates an expression node.

```
xpNode* createExpressionNode(char token[], xpNode *left, xpNode *right)
```

This is where I am struggling to grasp the recursive concept, this is the pseudocode I've come up with to help me understand how this should work. I would appreciate it if someone could take a look and shed some light on what to do when the stack is empty, and if there's anything else wrong here.

```
xpNode* createTree(Stack *stack){
{
   xpNode *node;
   get the top of the stack and store it in data
   pop the stack
   if the stack is empty, do something //im lost on what to do here
   if the top is an integer, node = createExpressionNode(data, NULL NULL) //the left and right arguments will always be NULL because integer's wont have any children
   if the top is a variable, node = createExpressionNode(data, NULL, NULL) //the left and right arguments will always be NULL because variables wont have any children
   if the top is an operator, node = createExpressionNode(data, createTree(stack), createTree(stack)) //Operators have children so we need to recursively get them

   return node
}
```

The result of the input: a b + should be a tree that looks like:

```
     +
    / \
   a   b
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the stack is empty, you're done.

Comment: So the user enters the expression in [reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), and you convert it to Polish notation on the stack?

Comment: @RussellZahniser yes, the user inputs the expression in post-fix notation.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the point of this representation that you don't *need* recursion? The logic should just be like

```
stack = an empty stack;
while (token = read_next_token()) {
  if (token is a term) {
    push(stack, createTerm(token));
  } else if (token is a unary operator) {
    push(stack, createUnOp(token, pop(stack)));
  } else if (token is a binary operator) {
    node *left, *right;
    left = pop(stack);
    right = pop(stack);
    push(stack, createBinOp(token, left, right));
  } else {
    error("unrecognized input");
  }
}
```

At the end of input, there should be one element on the stack, which is a tree representing the whole expression. If there's more than one element on the stack at the end, then the input was malformed. If at any point you tried to pop the stack when it was empty, the input was malformed.

Comment: +1, unfortunately, the OP took the second-to-last op (the binary op) quite literally to what you have here, and [introduced both a sequence point and by-val condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899233/double-free-or-corruption-error-with-stack-and-binary-expression-tree). But hey, live and learn. This answer is correct, and IMHO should have been marked as the answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'll edit my answer anyway to avoid the ordering issue :)

Answer (score 0):

If the stack is empty there, then there was an error in the input format. For example, if the stack is `[+ * 2 3]`, you can't build a tree - one more value is needed.

Comment: The stack will always eventually be empty right? Is there an issue in the order of which I am checking things perhaps?

Comment: @FatalProphet in a perfect parse the stack will have ONE element (the results of the entire parse), and `$` (epsilon) for the next input.