# Double free or corruption error with Stack and Binary Expression Tree

Tags: c, stack, free

I am getting the following error when trying to build a binary expression tree from a Stack. I believe the issue is where I am popping in the recursive function, I think I am popping on an empty stack but I don't know the solution.

*** glibc detected**  ./interp: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0934d018 **

Here is my code:

```
//This is the main
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   TreeNode *node;
   StackNode *stack = NULL;
   push(&stack, "a");
   push(&stack, "b");
   push(&stack, "+");
   //while (emptyStack(stack)!= 1){ //this while loop works correctly, which verifies that my stack implementation is working.
   //  printf("Top is : %s\n", top(stack));
   //  pop(&stack);
   //}
   node = buildTree(stack);


//buildTree function
TreeNode *buildTree(StackNode *stack){
   int integer; //to check for an integer
   char *data = top(stack);
   char *pch = strchr(top(stack), '.'); //to check for a double, looks for the decimal point
   if (emptyStack(stack) != 0){
       //stack is empty
       fprintf(stderr, "Invalid expression, not enough tokens");
       return NULL;
   }
   else if (sscanf(top(stack), "%d", &integer) != 0){
       printf("parser: integer node\n");
       //got an integer
       pop(&stack);
       return makeTreeNode(data, NULL, NULL);
   }
   else if (pch != NULL){
       printf("parser: double node\n");
       //got a double
       pop(&stack);
       return makeTreeNode(data, NULL, NULL);
   }
   else if ( isalpha((int)data[0])){
       //got a variable
       printf("parser: variable node\n");
       pop(&stack);
       return makeTreeNode(data, NULL, NULL);
   }
   else{
       //got an operator, recurse
       printf("parser: operator node\n");
       pop(&stack);
       return makeTreeNode(data,buildTree(stack), buildTree(stack));
   }
}

//makeTreeNode
TreeNode* makeTreeNode(char token[], TreeNode* left, TreeNode* right){
    //this function works correctly
```

Here are my stack functions

```
StackNode* makeStackNode(char* data, StackNode* next){
   StackNode *node;
   node = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
   node->data = data;
   node->next = next;
   printf("Making stack node of : %s\n", data);
   return node;
}


char* top(StackNode* stack){
   if (emptyStack(stack)!= 0){
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else{
      return stack->data;
   }
}

void push(StackNode** stack, char* data){
   StackNode* ptr;
   ptr = makeStackNode(data, *stack);
   *stack = ptr;
   printf("Pushed stack node \n");
}

//pop from stack
void pop (StackNode** stack){
   if (emptyStack(*stack)!=0){
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else{
      printf("Popping node \n");
      StackNode* ptr = *stack;
      printf("Right before the pop, stack = %s\n", top(*stack));
      *stack = ptr->next;
      printf("Right before the free, stack = %s\n", top(*stack));
      free(ptr);
   } 
}

//returns 1 if stack is empty, 0 if it is not empty
int emptyStack(StackNode* stack){
   if (stack == NULL){
      return 1;
   }
   else{
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Output from prints:

```
Making stack node of : a
Pushed stack node
Making stack node of : b
Pushed stack node
Making stack node of : +
Pushed stack node
parser: operator node
Popping node
Right before the pop, stack = +
Right before the free, stack = b
parser: variable node
Popping node
Right before the pop, stack = b
Right before the free, stack = a
parser: integer node //this should be a variable node
Popping node
Right before the pop, stack = //this should be stack = a
Right before the free, stack = a  //this should be blank
```

Comment: Did you write `pop` and `push`? Can you show the code for them? Put a `printf` statement in them to say "popping" and "pushing" so you can count them? Obviously if you pop something you didn't push you will get this error. If these are not "your" functions, create `myPop` and `myPush` and use them to intercept / count your calls… (increment / decrement stack counter, print message, and call 'regular' `push`/`pop`.

Comment: I've edited to include the functions, I will now add some print statements in the pop and push and report my findings.

Comment: Running valgrind may help.

Comment: What does `emptyStack` look like?… I would put additional debug statements right before `free(ptr);`. What is the content of `stack` at this point?

Comment: I've updated the output to reflect a print of the top of the stack right before we actually perform the pop, and after. Notice the second to last print, stack is blank? I assume that is the issue.

Comment: I just traced through the recursion by hand and I don't see how it's crashing, it seems like it should work with no problems when I traced it.

Comment: I can't figure out how your code produces the output you're provided. Where do you `printf` "Right before the pop"? That string isn't anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: Sorry @godel9, I just updated them, I forgot to reflect the changes here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
return makeTreeNode(data, buildTree(stack), buildTree(stack));
```

What value for `stack` do you think is being passed to each of those functions invocations?

Answer: The *same* value. When one (we don't know, no care which, as that is a sequence point issue), The other invoke takes the same stack pointer at the same (now-freed) node, and runs happily along thinking life is great, when in reality, its about to drive down the road of undefined behavior.

Your stack needs to be passed by-address to `buildTree()`, just as it is in the other places in your stack management functions (because that is exactly what `buildTree()` is doing: managing the input stack).

Finally once you fix that, you then need to fix the sequence-point issue of that function call, but that I leave to you. (Not really, see below)

```
//buildTree function
TreeNode *buildTree(StackNode **stack)
{
    char *data=NULL;
    int integer;

    if (stack == NULL)
    {
        //stack is empty
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid expression, not enough tokens");
        return NULL;
    }

    // reference top of stack data
    data = top(*stack);

    if (strchr(data,'.') != NULL)
    {
        printf("parser: double node\n");
        pop(stack);
        return makeTreeNode(data, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (sscanf(data, "%d", &integer) != 0)
    {
        printf("parser: integer node\n");
        pop(stack);
        return makeTreeNode(data, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if ( isalpha((int)data[0]))
    {
        printf("parser: variable node\n");
        pop(stack);
        return makeTreeNode(data, NULL, NULL);
    }

    //got an operator, recurse
    printf("parser: operator node\n");
    pop(stack);

    TreeNode *rhs = buildTree(stack);
    TreeNode *lhs = buildTree(stack);
    return makeTreeNode(data, lhs, rhs);
}

//This is the main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TreeNode *node;
    StackNode *stack = NULL;
    push(&stack, "a");
    push(&stack, "b");
    push(&stack, "+");
    node = buildTree(&stack);
}
```

**Output**

```
parser: operator node
parser: variable node
parser: variable node
```

Side Note: I did some cleanup on `buildTree()`, including reversing which you check for first: a decimal or an integer. 123.456 run through `sscanf(data, "%d", &integer)` will happily suck `123` out, and that isn't what you wanted by the looks of this.

Comment: Simply accepting your answer and upvoting is not even close to showing how much I appreciate your help, thank you very much. I would've never gotten this, I am still a C newbie. I was curious why some of the stack functions required a pointer-to-address argument, and now I know why!

Comment: @FatalProphet No problem. glad to help. it was subtle.

Comment: I have some memory leaks with the test code we used for this. I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to put the entire valgrind output here.                                                            ==13284==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 3 frees, 416 bytes allocated

==13284== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==13284== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2

Comment: @FatalProphet its likely a different issue, and thus a different question. but be warned that valgrind output is usually right, and rather detailed. so posting on SO with "where's my leak" when valgrind tells you where it is has a tendency to get... warm =P

Comment: another question for you! The recursive buildTree function here is calling data = top(stack) on an empty stack, which is causing the program to exit on failure. Any ideas?

Comment: Disregard previous comment, I found the bug! :P It was an extra call to top(*stack) for debugging purposes in pop.